# Argument is returning empty value on console.log

Tags: javascript, arguments

I am trying to pass an argument down the tree to the successResponse errorResponse functions and display the value in the console before I do any work with it.

Currently I am getting an empty value in the console so there must be something missing in my code. I am thinking its a return statement but when I attempt this I get no result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The console.log is below.

```
successResponse: function (getSel) {
        requestResponses.errorCode = false;
        requestResponses.redLight.removeClass(requestResponses.redBright);
        requestResponses.greenLight.addClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
        console.log(getSel);
    },
```

Here is the full version of my code

```
var requestResponses = {

    greenLight: $('.cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed'),
    redLight: $('.cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed'),
    greenBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--greenBright',
    redBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--redBright',

    settings: {
        flashError: 400,
        requestTime: 10000
    },

    init: function (url, getSel) {
        requestResponses.url = url;
        requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url, getSel);
        setInterval(function () {
            if (requestResponses.errorCode === true) {
                requestResponses.redLight.toggleClass(requestResponses.redBright);
            }
        }, requestResponses.settings.flashError);
    },

    successResponse: function (getSel) {
        requestResponses.errorCode = false;
        requestResponses.redLight.removeClass(requestResponses.redBright);
        requestResponses.greenLight.addClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
        console.log(getSel);
    },

    errorResponse: function () {
        requestResponses.greenLight.removeClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
    },

    getResponse: function (serverURL, getSel) {
        $.ajax(serverURL, {
            success: function (getSel) {
                requestResponses.errorCode = false;
                requestResponses.successResponse(getSel);
            },
            error: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = true;
                requestResponses.errorResponse();
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url);
                }, requestResponses.settings.requestTime);
            }
        });
    },

    errorCode: false
}

requestResponses.init('/status');
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: In your ajax success, does getSel has a value?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Make sure that the server actually responds with data. The problem is most likely on back-end.